# how to use distinct in ms access

Tags: sql, ms-access, distinct, ms-access-2003

I have two tables. Task and Categories.

[image: Task Table]

[image: Categories Table]

TaskID is not a primary key as there are duplicate values.When there are multiple contacts are selected for a specific task,taskid and other details will be duplicated.I wrote the query:

```
SELECT Priority, Subject, Status, DueDate, Completed, Category
FROM Task, Categories
WHERE Categories.CategoryID=Task.CategoryID;
```

[image: Query Result]

Now as multiple contacts are selected for that task,for the taskid=T4, there are two records(highlighted with gray). I have tried using distinct in ms access 2003 but its not working. I want to display distinct records. (Here there's no requirement to show taskid) If I write :

```
select priority, distinct(subject), .......
```

and remaining same as mentioned in above query then its giving me an error. I have tried distinctrow also.But didnt get success. How to get distinct values in ms access?

Comment: What's the PK of your Task table?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Okay.Its working this way.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Task.Priority, Task.Subject, Task.Status, Task.DueDate, 
Task.Completed, Categories.Category
FROM Task, Categories
WHERE (((Categories.CategoryID)=[Task].[CategoryID]));
```

Answer (score 5):

I don't like using SELECT DISTINCT, I have found that it makes my code take longer to compile.  The other way I do it is by using GROUP BY.

```
    SELECT Priority, Subject, Status, DueDate, Completed, Category
    FROM Task, Categories
    WHERE Categories.CategoryID=Task.CategoryID
    GROUP BY Subject;
```

I do not have VBA up at the moment but this should work as well.

Comment: if you want to replace DISTINCT with GROUP BY you need to add ALL YOUR output fields to the GROUP BY clause

Answer (score 3):

Using SELECT DISTINCT will work for you, but a better solution here would be to change your database design.

Duplicate records may lead to inconsistent data. For example, imagine having two different status in different records with the same TaskID. Which one would be right?

A better design would include something like a Task table, a Contact table and an Assignment table, as follows (the fields in brackets are the PK):

Tasks: [TaskID], TaskPriority, Subject, Status, DueDate, Completed, StartDate, Owner, CategoryID, ContactID, ...

Contact: [ID], Name, Surname, Address, PhoneNumber, ...

Assignment: [TaskID, ContactID]

Then, you can retrieve the Tasks with a simple SELECT from the Tasks tables.
And whenever you need to know the contacts assigned to a Tasks, you would do so using the JOIN clause, like this

```
SELECT T.*, C.*
FROM TaskID as T 
  INNER JOIN Assignment as A
    ON T.TaskID = A.TaskID
  INNER JOIN Contac as C
    ON A.ContactID = C.ID
```

Or similar. You can filter, sort or group the results using all of SQL's query power.