# MS Access 2010 - SQL Query using RIGHT JOIN - Returning too much values

Tags: sql, ms-access, join

I'm trying to make  this query but it's returning too much rows

```
SELECT 
Denuncia.codigoAsociado,    
Involucrado.nombreCompleto 
FROM 
Denuncia 
RIGHT JOIN 
Involucrado ON Denuncia.ID = Involucrado.idDenuncia
```

I would like to get one codigoAsociado and one nombreCompleto. I have tried using DISTINCT but it's the same.

This is the result (check the link) Sorry can't post images

http://oi62.tinypic.com/2l9gwnp.jpg

I need it to look like this

codigoAsociado | nombreCompleto

341130402      | Juan Carlos Espinoza López

341131290      | Carlos Queirolo Rochabrun

.

.

.

341131600      | Enrique Froemel

341131949      | Raúl Muñoz

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I use Oracle DB but in Access should work this:

```
SELECT 
TOP 1 Denuncia.codigoAsociado,    
Involucrado.nombreCompleto 
FROM 
Denuncia 
RIGHT JOIN 
Involucrado ON Denuncia.ID = Involucrado.idDenuncia
```

The TOP number tell you how many rows will be returned. You should also use TOP 10 PERCENT and it returns first 10% of records.

If you need only unique records, try to use this code

```
SELECT 
DISTINCT Denuncia.codigoAsociado,    
Involucrado.nombreCompleto 
FROM 
Denuncia 
RIGHT JOIN 
Involucrado ON Denuncia.ID = Involucrado.idDenuncia
```

DISTINCT in Access has been also discussed in this post [how to use distinct in ms access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5788586/how-to-use-distinct-in-ms-access).