# Using Ms Access simple joining giving me repeated data

Tags: ms-access

**(i want distinct in msaccess query)**
i have two tables where my data is matching and repeating in datagridview im working on report plz help me

here is my simple join query

```
select Labortary.Test_Name,Labortary.Test_Charges,LabortaryTestRecord.[Total Amount] 
from LabortaryTestRecord,Labortary
where LabortaryTestRecord.[PatientID]=Labortary.Patient_id
and LabortaryTestRecord.[PatientID]=34
```

Comment: Have you tried adding the `DISTINCT` keyword to your query? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5788586/how-to-use-distinct-in-ms-access

Comment: yes now its right thanks HHH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must add DISTINCT keyword:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Labortary.Test_Name,Labortary.Test_Charges,
 LabortaryTestRecord.[Total Amount] 
FROM LabortaryTestRecord,Labortary
WHERE LabortaryTestRecord.[PatientID]=Labortary.Patient_id
   and LabortaryTestRecord.[PatientID]=34
```

Comment: yes thanks i solved my problem writing distinct key word