# How do I get to run a query that consolidates rows?

Tags: sql, ms-access

My data looks like

```
 Name, City, Zip
Bob, ATown, 00000
Bill, ATown, 00000
Ant, ATown, 00000
Jill, BTown, 00000
```

I want to run a query so I can get the results that look like

```
Zip, City
00000, ATown
00001, BTown
00002, CTown
```

The zip is not listed more than once

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5788586/how-to-use-distinct-in-ms-access Please have alook at this article and tell me if it will help you?

Comment: your sample data has same zip value for all rows!?

Comment: No, Thats just a sample of what his data looks. I guess he has Many Names who live at the same zipcode and he just wants one of each zip code. @krishKM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY, ZIP
```

Would this not work?

Comment: Access doesnt understand DISTINCT

Comment: But inn this article, they use distinct http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5788586/how-to-use-distinct-in-ms-access

Comment: I also have this article from msdna and they use distinct ? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd638587(v=office.12).aspx